# jq how to merge array objects into single object

Tags: jq

in jq its possible to add objects using the + operator

if you have an array

```
 [
      {
        "a": "value"
      },
      {
        "b": "value"
      },
      {
        "c": "value"
      }
 ]
```

I want to convert it into a single object { a:"value", b:"value", c:"value" }
I can use the following filter .[0] + .[1] + .[2], but i want to do it for the whole array without specifying all the indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is just to call [`add` filter](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#add).

> *"The filter `add` takes as input an array, and produces as output the elements of the array added together. This might mean summed, concatenated or merged depending on the types of the elements of the input array - the rules are the same as those for the `+` operator (described above)."*
>
> ---
>
> <sup>Source: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#add</sup>

```
$ cat test.json 
[ 
    {
        "a": "value"
    },
    {
        "b": "value"
    },
    {
        "c": "value"
    }
 ]

$ jq 'add' test.json
{
  "a": "value",
  "b": "value",
  "c": "value"
}
```

As mentioned by [peak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997358/peak) in the comment, you can even skip wrapping `add` filter with the quotes:

```
$ jq add test.json
{
  "a": "value",
  "b": "value",
  "c": "value"
}
```

Comment: Even simpler: `jq add test.json` :-)

Comment: Wow didn't know about `add`. jq truly is a masterpiece

Comment: @peak Oh yes, indeed :-D

Answer (score 4):

You can use `reduce`:

```
reduce .[] as $o ({}; . + $o)
```

returns:

```
{
  "a": "value",
  "b": "value",
  "c": "value"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to merge all objects in array recursively (didn't find any similar answer here):

```
jq 'reduce .[] as $x ({}; . * $x)'
```

Comment: This is merging just the different keys. The similar keys are not being merged. They are going to be overrided.